# integrity constraint in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, foreign-keys, database-integrity

Suppose that a table named `SuplProd` has the columns `supplier` and `product` and two entries: `(Sony Ericcson, Xperia)` and `(Apple, iPhone)`.

I would like to create a table named `Orders` with columns `supplier`, `product` and `quantity`.

However, I'd like the combination `(supplier, product)` of table `Orders` to be limited to contain only entries from `SuplProd`.

For example, the entry `(Sony Ericcson, Xperia, 1)` would be valid for the table `Orders` whereas `(Apple, Xperia, 1)` would not.

How is this possible in Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a foreign key in orders table:

```
create table SuplProd (
   supplier ...,
   product ...,
   constraint SuplProd_pk 
     primary key( supplier, product)
)

create table Orders
   ...
   supplier ...,
   product ...,
   qty,
   constraint SuplProd_pk 
     primary key( ... ),
   constraint orders_to_suplprod_fk
     foreign key ( supplier, product)
     references SuplPRod (supplier, product)
)
```

Comment: If  SuplProd already has a primary key, then a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT would work as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, right! thanks about appointment. Also if SuplProd has a primary key you can replace supplier, product in Orders table by a copy of SuplProd primary key field(s).